# ADB lock screen with broken screen ( Pattern)

Tags: android, adb

My phone ( android 5.0.2) have a pattern for password and broken screen,NO ROOTED.

I try this software (http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2786395)for control my phone but I can't unlock my android device.

Can you give a solution for delete lock screen (I have tried this -> adb shell rm /data/system/gesture.key but I don't have permission)/others tools or others solutions?

Comment: I just tried `adb shell su` and i got this **error : /system/bin/sh: su: not found** .(I'm on windows,and my device isn't rooted)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove any lock or pattern by deleting a file *.key located in /data/system.

You will need a shell and a rooted phone.

Otherwise, you could install a clockworkmod recovery that comes with an adb shell and use it to get full access to the file system.

Hope this helps.

Comment: So i root my phone and use `adb shell rm /data/system/gesture.key `  in CMD?

Comment: Dont need to root anything, just install CWM, launch it, get the adb shell and call: cd /system/data then rm *.key of course you dont need CWM if you root the phone.

Answer (score 0):

if you aren't a root, you can not access the key file. So you can not change key or delete it. You must be root for deleting key file or changing the key file. Sorry.

Comment: you can not access the key file when you are INSIDE Android, when you are outside system permissions have no meaning.

Answer (score 0):

You can only install a custom recovery if your bootloader is unlocked. On Nexus devices this wipes the device, I don't know about other devices. Many are not even capable of being unlocked.

So the solution to install a custom recovery to get write access to the system partition is not likely to work unless you've previously unlocked your bootloader.